# How Mock throw from axios

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, vue.js

How I can to mock in my unit testing the throw exception.

I try to test like this : `expect(service.methodA).toThrowError('error');`

I have this message :

Expected the function to throw an error matching:
      `"error"`. But it didn't throw anything.

```
return this.service.post(
            URL,
        ).pipe(
            map(response => response.data),
            catchError(error => {
              throw new Error('error');
             })
        ).toPromise();
```

Thank you

Comment: have you tried calling the method ? `expect(service.methodA()).toThrowError('error');`

Comment: Add more of your test so we can see how are you implementing it, please.

Comment: If the post method doesn't throw anything, there's no reason for the catchError to be triggered. return this.service.post(URL).pipe(tap(() => throw new Error('error'))).toPromise();

Comment: Yes but is it possible to mock this httpService from Axios to  trigger an error ? In my unit test I have one spy on my service : `jest.spyOn(httpService, 'post').mockImplementation(() => of<AxiosResponse<ClassA>>(data));` Because I must to have 100% in my unit test and this line is not cover ...

Comment: Hey did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes I changed  by toPromise().catch(e => e);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say about mocking an Exception with axios?

I don't know which library are you using.

For example with Sinon, I wrote like that:

```
let sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

sandbox.stub(axios, "post").onFirstCall().returns(Promise.resolve(//Exception goes here))
```